# PostgreSQL: JSON field is datatype text, I need nested values out

Tags: json, postgresql, azure, text

I have the following data stored in a PostgreSQL field that's designated as text, not JSON:

```
{"description_translated": "{\"en\": \"Description in English\", \"fr\": \"Descriptif en français\"}", "name_translated": "{\"en\": \"Name in English\", \"fr\": \"Nom en français\"}", "resource_lang": "English"}
```

The application set up the database with the field where JSON is stored as a text field.

I know I can extract something "top level" like "resource_lang" thus:

```
Select extras::json -> 'resource_lang'
```

but if I want to get the English string for 'description_translated' these don't work, both return null:

```
select extras::json -> 'description_translated' ->> 'en' as desc_en
```

```
select extras::json -> 'description_translated' -> 'en' as desc_en
```

I've tried cockamamie stuff like this:

```
select extras::json -> 'description_translated'::json -> 'en' as desc_en
```

of course that doesn't work, so is there a way to get my nested values out?

What I want to get out would be desc_en = "Description in English"

Comment: The problem are the escaped double quotes. So the value for the key `description_translated` is one large JSON string. It's **not** a nested JSON structure. For that it would need to be `{"description_translated": {"en": "Description in English", "fr": "Description in English"}, ... }`. You can see that if you use `extras::json ->> 'description_translated'`

Answer (score 0):

Due to a bad json conversion your text field ended as non valid/bad formed json,
but could be fixed with a couple of replacements, as:

```
select
regexp_replace( 
regexp_replace(
'{"description_translated": "{\"en\": \"Description in English\", \"fr\": \"Descriptif en français\"}", "name_translated": "{\"en\": \"Name in English\", \"fr\": \"Nom en français\"}", "resource_lang": "English"}'
,'\\','','g'),'"({)|(})"','\1\2','g')::json -> 'description_translated' ->> 'en';
```

this way it returns your value "Description in English"

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/100197)

Comment: So can I do a single query that will pull the value from the field, then store the result of the regexp and then I can "operate" on that with the standard -> operators?

Comment: Yes you could add a json type column over the same table and do an `update table1 set json_type_field=regexp_replace(regexp_replace(bad_formed_json,'\\','','g'),'"({)|(})"','\1\2','g')::json where <condition>;`, or do an `insert into table2(field1, field2 ...)
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(bad_formed_json,'\\','','g'),'"({)|(})"','\1\2','g')::json from table1;` over another table, and then make use of json operators to access info normally.